# How can I write an exponent for another number in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I need to write n, in the formula below, as an exponent. Any ideas on how I can do that since I can't use the ^ sign in C#.
Thanks

I already used the ^ sign but it doesnt work.

```
//Calculation

P = L x[(1 + .00583)^n * .00583] / [(1 + .00583)^n - 1];
//P = L*c(1 + c)n(1 + c)n−1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Math.Pow static Method.

```
Math.Pow(Double, Double)
```

So your expression could be written in the form :

```
    P = (L * Math.Pow(1 + .00583,n) * .00583) / (Math.Pow(1 + .00583,n) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Math class' method "Pow"
example:

```
Math.Pow(1 + .00583, n)
```

and only use normal brackets ()